# SSRS issue embed to web application

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, x-frame-options

We are using the below to Embed SSRS reports into web application. The report server is all set and is working fine when used the link separately. Using below to embed into web app

I start getting this error
Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

This X-frame-options is only coming in new version of sql .
Old version SQL 2012 , No  frame options and is working fine. ABle to see resullts.

Is there a way to fix this? TIA. Please help!!!!

tried to by pass x-frame options and it didnt work
I want to be able to see ssrs reports inside web application

Answer (score 0):

Rather than embedding your report server directly into your app via IFRAME consider using the report viewer control:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16